# Problema al llenar un combo box en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Resulta que en una base de datos mysql tengo algunos registro y necesito se reflejen en un JComboBox de java pero no encuentro el error

tengo una clase que se encarga de la conexion a la base de datos y dentro de ella hago ese metodo

```
106   public void llenarCmbCurso(JComboBox cmbCurso){
 107               cmbCurso.removeAllItems();
 108           try{
 109               String query = "SELECT C_codCurso  FROM t_curso ";
 110               PreparedStatement ps =conect.prepareStatement(query);
 111               ResultSet rest = ps.executeQuery();
 112               
 113           while(rest.next()){
 114                   cmbCurso.addItem(rest.getString("C_codCurso")); 
 115              }
 116           
 117          }catch(SQLException  e ){
 118               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 119               
 120           }  
 121       }
```

En en JFrame donde quiero mostrar tal cosa hago lo siguiente

```
 18   Conexion con = new Conexion();
 19    public FMateria() {
 20       initComponents();
 21       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 22       deshabilitar();
 23       con.llenarCmbCurso(cmbCodCurso);
 24    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes contar algo más de lo que hace este código: devuelve algún error, pasa por la consulta y el llenado del combo pero no muestra nada, etc?

Comment: eption in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at conexion.Conexion.llenarCmbCurso(Conexion.java:110)
 at Vista.FMateria.<init>(FMateria.java:23) .    La linea 110 es `PreparedStatement ps =conect.prepareStatement(query);`  de la clase Conexion y la 23 `con.llenarCmbCurso(cmbCodCurso);` de la clase del JFrame FMateria

Comment: ¿Qué línea es exactamente la que falla? Recuerda que aquí no tenemos información sobre números de línea como los puedes ver tú en tu editor. Pone algo de la línea 110 dentro del fichero Conexion.java y la 23 del FMateria.java. Actualiza el post con esas líneas

Comment: mira @JaviMollá

Comment: Estás usando una variable llamada `conect` que no está inicializada

Comment: Claro que sí, si esa es la que me hace la conexión a la base de datos, si fuera por eso no me dejara ni siquiera insertar registro pero revisaré bien si es lo que dices, gracias